# How to instantiate a Room object called room1 and print with string representation of room1 in python?

Tags: python

I am doing a question where it is telling me to instantiate a `Room` object called `room1` with `size = 132, view = 'City', type = 'Double', and basicRates = 120`. Then, I have to print a string representation of room1. How should I do this?

Comment: Could you share Room class ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
class Room():
    size = 0
    view = ""
    type_ = ""
    basic_rates = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Size: ' + str(self.size) + '\n' + 'View: ' + self.view + '\n' + \
            'Type: ' + self.type_ + '\n' + \
            'Basic Rates: ' + str(self.basic_rates)


room1 = Room()
room1.size = 132
room1.view = 'City'
room1.type_ = 'Double'
room1.basic_rates = 120

print(room1.__str__())
```

Also, you should read about [Python Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)